# Syntax error importing pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I just installed pandasql and keep getting an error importing as specified in the usage guide. I seem a bit lost. I installed the package with sudo since I was also getting permission denied on python folder. would appreciate some wisdom:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: from pandasql import sqldf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py",  line 98
return {**outer_frame.frame.f_globals,
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax****
```

Comment: Always write which versions of Python and installed packages you are using. This version of pandasql is apparently not compatible with Python 2.x, and you need Python 3.x.